# month year sql server 2008 order by date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have a table that contain a column of date in month/year format.

```
06/14
02/14
01/14
03/14
```

How to order by date that column of date.

i am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Please post your table structure (fields name...). You can use an ORDER BY clause on your field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could accomplish this by using the [**CAST()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function in your `ORDER BY` statement [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8ccf1/1/0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY CAST ('01/' + monthYear AS date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a date data type to store dates, but it looks like you are using a varchar.  So you'll have to ORDER BY part of the string:

```
ORDER BY RIGHT(datecol,2), datecol
```

Where datecol is the name of your field.  The second datecol will effectively order by the month after the first one orders by year.